# coroutine was never awaited error in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, telethon

I wrote a code which is working and I wanted to turn my program into a GUI program.
Whenever I run the program I get this error :

```
C:\Users\Mohamad Bilal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py:888: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'start_sending' was never awaited
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
```

Here's My code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
import os
from telethon import TelegramClient
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import threading

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, bg='#263D42')
canvas.pack()
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='white')
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)
load_excel = tk.Button(root, text='Load Excel', padx=10, pady=5, fg='white', bg='#263D42', command=load_excel)
product_count_txt = tk.Entry(root)
product_count_txt.insert(0, '1')
channel = tk.Entry(root, )
channel.insert(0, 'mohammadbelal')

product_count_txt.pack()
channel.pack()
load_excel.pack()
wb = xl.load_workbook('new.xlsx')

sheet = wb['Sheet1']
api_id = 
api_hash = ''
token = ''
phone = ''
client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)


async def start_sending():
    await client.connect()
    if not client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.send_code_request(phone)
        await client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
    pp = await product_count_txt.get()
    product_count = int(pp)
    receiver = await channel.get()

    for i in range(product_count):
        s = i + 2
        d = await sheet.cell(s, 3)
        price = await sheet.cell(s, 27)
        seri = await sheet.cell(s, 43)
        sku = await d.value
        size = await sheet.cell(s, 7)
        message = f'''<b>Package (Seri) :</b> {seri.value} Pcs
    <b>Size:</b> {size.value[343:-350]}
    </br>
    <b>Price:</b> {price.value} $
    <b>Code:</b> {sku}
    
    <b>Whatsapp for more info:</b>
    +90 541 841 66 36
    
    <b><a href="https://www.facebook.com/istabuyGCC/">Facebook</a> |
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/istabuy/">Instagram</a> | istabuy.com®</b>
    '''
        image = []
        for folder, subs, files in os.walk('images\\' + sku):
            for filename in files:
                if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
                    await image.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, filename)))
        await client.send_file(receiver, image)
        await client.send_message(receiver, message, parse_mode='html', link_preview=False)
        print(sku, 'Has been Sent!')


start_sending_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Start Sending', padx=10, pady=5, fg='white', bg='#263D42',
                              command=threading.Thread(target=start_sending).start())

start_sending_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: see [this example](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon_examples/gui.py) on how to integrate telethon with tkinter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `tkinter`, but to run async functions I've always used and also seen used [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html).

```
import asyncio

async def function_name():
    # your code

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(function_name())
```

Comment: It didn't work :( still says coroutine never been awaited

Comment: @MhamadBelal that because you're calling `start_sending` using `command=threading.Thread(target=start_sending)` probably.. try using `command=threading.Thread(target=await start_sending)` instead. By the way imho you should just use asyncio instead of threading

Comment: when I used target=await start_sending it says "SyntaxError: 'await' outside function"

Comment: that's because you're mixing asyncio and threading, use just asyncio and you will be fine

Comment: @TheKill-996 you can easily run additional events loops in other Thread if you want (no idea why anybody could need it). Please find example for similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68652643/10311377

Comment: @MhamadBelal you can easily run additional events loops in other Thread if you want (no idea why anybody could need it). Please find example for similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68652643/10311377