# Asyncio error "There is no current event loop in thread" when using with a flask program

Tags: python, flask, python-asyncio, pyserial

I am making a small webpage which controls a [Microbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Bit) and shows some sensor data.

I am trying to implement asynchronous read and writes to the microbit through my flask backend based on the things I click on the front end.

But when I use flask to run a function I have it gives an error which says

```
  "There is no current event loop in thread"
```

The function looks like this. It initializes the library I am using for async serial communication.

```
import aioserial
import asyncio
import serial



def test1():
     return aioserial.AioSerial(port='COM5', baudrate = 115200)
     
print(test1())
```

When I run this file the output is as expected

```
AioSerial<id=0x1c5a373ed90, open=True>(port='COM5', baudrate=115200, bytesize=8, parity='N', 
stopbits=1, timeout=None, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)
```

However when I call the same function from a flask function

```
@app.before_first_request
def startserial():
    global aioserialinstance
    try:
        portaddress = find_comport(PID_MICROBIT, VID_MICROBIT, 115200)
        print(portaddress)
        aioserialinstance = test1()

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    print("device not connected or wrong port number")
```

I get this error

```
  File "C:\Users\adity\Documents\Brbytes Folder\lessons-interactive\2021\Flask-microbit\app.py", line 23, in startserial
    aioserialinstance = aioserial.AioSerial(port='COM5', baudrate = 115200)
  File "C:\Users\adity\Documents\Brbytes Folder\lessons-interactive\2021\Flask-microbit\venv\Lib\site-packages\aioserial\aioserial.py", line 57, in __init__
    self._read_lock: asyncio.Lock = asyncio.Lock()
  File "C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\asyncio\locks.py", line 81, in __init__
    self._loop = events.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\adity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
```

I am not sure what is causing this error when I run it with flask app. When I make some test programs and reading,writing everything works perfectly but on importing these functions into the flask app.py breaks them with this error.

I do not have much knowledge of asyncio and I am completely out of ideas to fix this.

Comment: Any feedback please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicates that there in no event loop in not MainThread, for async programs in Python we usually have only one `asyncio` loop in MainThread, we do not want more `asyncio` loops, since they'll be fighting each other for time and the whole app will be slower and more prone to errors.

If I were you I would use `aiohttp` or any other async http framework instead of Flask, otherwise use any other not async library for `serial port`.

But how you can get another loop in not MainThread if you want it? Please find example:

```py
import asyncio
from threading import Thread, current_thread


async def async_job():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print(f"{current_thread().getName()}___Hurray!\n")


def asyncio_wrapper_function():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    except RuntimeError as ex:
        print(ex)
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(async_job())
    finally:
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ths = [
        Thread(target=asyncio_wrapper_function, name=f"Th-{i}") for i in range(4)
    ]
    [i.start() for i in ths]
    [i.join() for i in ths]

    print("All work done!")
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped I didnt try another loop in mainthread but I used the flask async add on and it worked.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/async-await/